# how to increase buffer size in scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm using a variable that is using too large symbol/string in **Scilab**, which is giving following error:

> Too large string. at line      44 of exec file called by :
>   exec('/proj/shubhamj/shubhamj/scilab/final_add_from_script.sce', -1)

I've already used `stacksize('max')`.

Comment: I haven't done Scilab in a very long time but after checking on the mailing list [here](http://mailinglists.scilab.org/too-large-string-td3389713.html) it seems that the error might actually come from the length of the command you are trying to execute and not from the stack size (since `exec(...)` tries exactly that - to run what you pass as argument).According to the [documentation](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/stacksize.html) the default stack size is approx. 76MB(yes, megabytes) and I really doubt that whatever you load (character-wise) takes up that much space.Post the SCE file

Comment: @rbaleksandar Thanx man, yes this was the issue. I was using string which was of length more than 80,000 (80k) characters, now I broke it up into smaller pieces and its working..:)

Comment: :) Will post it as answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://mailinglists.scilab.org/too-large-string-td3389713.html) on the mailing list for Scilab the error comes from the length of the command. You can get the same error without the `exec()` if you call a command that is too long even in your current script (where the `exec()` call currently is).

If we look at the [documentation](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/stacksize.html) the default stacksize is approx. **76MB** (megabytes) and that is a lot of characters which makes this issue 99.9% not related to the size of the stack.